# How do I link boost to my program?

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, linker

I downloaded Boost 1.54 and ran `bootstrap.bat mingw`.  Then I tried to run the program below. I am getting the error you see below.  I have tried copying my boost folder into the mingw include folder and I have tried linking my file to the `boost/stage/lib` folder, but I have not been successful.  I see a lot of questions similar to this question, but none of them explain how to get the link the boost folder to the file.

Do I have to copy the boost folder to a different directory?  Do I have to change my path variable? How can I get the boost library to link to my code?

## Code

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>   
#include <iostream>              

using namespace std; 
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator iterator(string("."));
    for(; iterator != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++iterator)
    {
        cout << (iterator->path().filename()) << endl;
    }

    boost::filesystem::path full_path( boost::filesystem::current_path() );
    std::cout << "Current path is : " << full_path << std::endl;
   return 0;

}
```

## Error

```
C:\Users\212340~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZA7umT.o:playground.cc:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
C:\Users\212340~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZA7umT.o:playground.cc:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:\Users\212340~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZA7umT.o:playground.cc:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:\Users\212340~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZA7umT.o:playground.cc:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\212340~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZA7umT.o: bad reloc address 0x1b in section `.text$_ZNK5boost6system10error_code7messageEv[__ZNK5boost6system10error_code7messageEv]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 21.0s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Usually you tell the linker the link directories (e.g. -LC:\boost\<libs>) and the library you need `-lboost_system`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Btw what is the point of writing `using namespace boost::filesystem` if you're using the fully qualified names anyway

Comment: Not a duplicate. +1 to the question and answer.

Comment: @Brandin good point, I changed the code so it was no longer redundant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Answer

`boost::system` must be linked explicitly. In contrast to many other parts of boost, boost system is not [header-only](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries). Thus, you must make sure to link it when you compile.  You have two options for linking.

*Reference:* http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library

### Option 1

Use `-lboost_system` (or the equivalent file in your /boost_#*##*#/stage/lib/ directory). Of course, you also have to set the library path using `-L/file/path/to/libraries` unless boost system resides in a standard lookup dir.

#### Example

```
g++ playground.cc -o playground -L~/boost/stage/lib/ -libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_54.a
```

### Option 2

Include the full file path to the library at the end of your code.

#### Example

Run this from the command line. The triple quotes `"""` are necessary only for paths that contain spaces.

```
g++ playground.cc -o playground """C:\My Programs\boost_1_54_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_54.a""" """C:\My Programs\boost_1_54_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_54.a"""
```

**Note:** For a list of files that are not header-only, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries (Same link as in the first paragraph on "header-only").

Comment: Can you give an example?  My guess is I need to do something like `g++ C:\My Programs\playground.cc -lboost_system -L C:\My Programs\boost_1_54_0\stage\lib\`, but I ran that and it gave me a `cannot find -lboost_system` error.

Comment: Kudos for this extended answer go to the OP firelight who edited it but was rejected while I was not here. Since the answer is good, however, I reposted his edit in order to preseve it.

Comment: Thank you for reposting the edit! I hope it saves some time for others who have the same problem